# CodeHS Java nitro

Tags: java

**Instructions**

> Your company is doing some data cleanup, and notices that the email list of all users has been getting outdated. For one, there are some users with repeat email addresses, and some of the email accounts no longer exist.

Your job is to create a series of methods that can purge some of the old data from the existing email list.

Create static methods in the DataPurge class that can do the following:

removeDuplicates This method takes an email list, and removes the duplicate email values. It also prints to the console which duplicate emails have been removed.

removeAOL This method removes all email addresses from a list that are from aol.com. It notifies the user which email addresses are being removed as well.

containsOnlyEmails This method returns true if all of the data in the email list is actually an email address. We will define something as an email address if it contains the characters @ and .
Test your methods out in the DataPurgeTester file. You don’t have to change anything there, but the methods should work accordingly!

Their code

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DataPurgeTester
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ArrayList<String> emails = new ArrayList<String>();
        addEmails(emails);
        System.out.println("List is all emails: " +DataPurge.containsOnlyEmails(emails));
        DataPurge.removeDuplicates(emails);
        DataPurge.removeAOL(emails);
        System.out.println(emails);
    }



    public static void addEmails(ArrayList<String> emails)
    {
        emails.add("tbmaddux@icloud.com");
        emails.add("rfisher@outlook.com");
        emails.add("anicolao@verizon.net");
        emails.add("openldap@me.com");
        emails.add("improv@gmail.com");
        emails.add("alias@sbcglobal.net");
        emails.add("portele@me.com");
        emails.add("doormat@icloud.com");
        emails.add("mailarc@aol.com");
        emails.add("portele@me.com");
        emails.add("rmcfarla@optonline.net");
        emails.add("chrisk@verizon.net");
        emails.add("gordonjcp@aol.com");
        emails.add("improv@gmail.com");
    }
}
```

My Code

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DataPurge
{
    public static void removeDuplicates(ArrayList<String> e)
    {
        String removed = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < e.size(); i++)
        {
          for (int x = 0; x < e.size(); x++)
          {
              if (e.get(i).equals(e.get(x)))
              {
                  removed += e.get(x) + "\n";
                  e.remove(x);
              }
          }
        }
        System.out.println(removed);
    }
    public static void removeAOL(ArrayList<String> e)
    {
       String removed = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < e.size(); i++)
        {
            String e2 = e.get(i);

           if(e2.indexOf("aol.com") != -1)
           {
               removed += e.get(i) + "\n";
               e.remove(i);
           }
        }
    }
    public static Boolean containsOnlyEmails(ArrayList<String> e)
    {
        int x = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < e.size(); i++)
        {
          if (e.get(i).indexOf("@") != -1 && e.get(i).indexOf(".") != -1) 
          {
              x++;
          }
        }
        return (x == e.size());
    }
}
```

Problems

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmq99.png
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtQUt.png

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. In the current state of your question, chances it is getting a relevant answer are fairly minimal, mainly because **you're not asking a question**. Also, your phrasing makes it look like you're asking people to do your homework for you, which they won't. Post code, output, errors you're getting, things you've tried so far, etc. For future questions, read about [how to create a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: What Java version are you using?

Comment: is this for a homework assignment? You really should ask your professor or any of your classmates help.

Comment: No, my teacher is currently out sick, and I am ahead of the rest of my class hence the post. If you look at the pictures in the problem you will see the test cases. I currently have no errors, I'm just not getting the expected result, which is also in the test cases. The code I currently have is in the My code section, I am not allowed to change their code.